# Basic Fibonacci sequence in C

Tags: c, console, fibonacci-sequence

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define RED     "\x1b[31m"
#define GREEN   "\x1b[32m"
#define YELLOW  "\x1b[33m"
#define BLUE    "\x1b[34m"
#define MAGENTA "\x1b[35m"
#define CYAN    "\x1b[36m"
#define RESET   "\x1b[0m"


int main () {

  int n1 = 1, n2 = 0, i = 0, limit = 0, neg = 0, pos = 0;
        printf("Enter first number > ");
  scanf("%d",&n1);
        printf("Enter the seconed number > ");
  scanf("%d",&n2);
        printf("Enter the number of terms > ");
  scanf("%d",&limit);

  for (i; i < limit; i++ ) {
                if (n2 >=1) { pos ++; printf( RESET "%i\n" RESET, n2); }
                if (n2 <=0) { neg ++; printf( MAGENTA   "%i\n" MAGENTA,  n2); }
    int temp = n2;

    n2 += n1;
    n1 = temp;
  }

        printf(RESET"\n***************************************************"RESET);
        printf("\nPositive numbers in range %i : %i\n",limit,pos);
        printf("Negitive : %i",neg);
  printf("\n***************************************************");
}
```

Comment: -1 Please provide the problem description and your desired level of review at a bare minimum. Questions solely comprising "Code!" merit only "You posted some code which probably could be improved" as a response. If this is your desired response, simply email your code to yourself. Everyone wins! :p

Answer (score 11):

## Things you could improve

#### Using Headers

- Right now you are defining some items at the top of your source file.

  > ```
  > #define RED     "\x1b[31m"
  > #define GREEN   "\x1b[32m"
  > #define YELLOW  "\x1b[33m"
  > #define BLUE    "\x1b[34m"
  > #define MAGENTA "\x1b[35m"
  > #define CYAN    "\x1b[36m"
  > #define RESET   "\x1b[0m"
  > ```

  These are all relatable, and reusable ANSI escape codes to color your text in a terminal, so you could put them all in their own header (`color.h`) for easy use with other files.

  ```
  #define BLACKTEXT(x) "\033[30;1m" x "\033[0m"
  #define REDTEXT(x) "\033[31;1m" x "\033[0m"
  #define GREENTEXT(x) "\033[32;1m" x "\033[0m"
  #define YELLOWTEXT(x) "\033[33;1m" x "\033[0m"
  #define BLUETEXT(x) "\033[34;1m" x "\033[0m"
  #define MAGENTATEXT(x) "\033[35;1m" x "\033[0m"
  #define CYANTEXT(x) "\033[36;1m" x "\033[0m"
  #define WHITETEXT(x) "\033[37;1m" x "\033[0m"
  ```

  Then you can just `#include "color.h"` in all of your files where you need some color in your terminal.
- As you can see from my own `color.h` header file, I don't have a `RESET` macro.  I didn't find a use for it, since I would always end up resetting the color right after I used it.  The way I have it defined, my macros can do that for me.

#### User Experience

- I find it useless to have to enter a first and second number.

  > ```
  >         printf("Enter first number > ");
  >   scanf("%d",&n1);
  >         printf("Enter the seconed number > ");
  >   scanf("%d",&n2);
  > ```

  What is the point of this?  Just start from \$ 0 \$ and \$ 1 \$, and go to \$ n \$ number of terms.

#### Efficiency/Algorithm

- Right now you can't compute that many fibonacci numbers, because of the maximum size of an `int`; you can only calculate numbers up to 32767.

  We aren't expecting negative numbers in our sequence, so we easily increase this restriction, you could use an `unsigned int` which has a maximum value of 65535, or even better, a `long long unsigned int` with a maximum value of 18446744073709551615. That's 562967131565294 times larger than your current program!
- Your algorithm can be simplified down using method extraction and recursion.

  > ```
  >   for (i; i < limit; i++ ) {
  >                 if (n2 >=1) { pos ++; printf( RESET "%i\n" RESET, n2); }
  >                 if (n2 <=0) { neg ++; printf( MAGENTA   "%i\n" MAGENTA,  n2); }
  >     int temp = n2;
  >
  >     n2 += n1;
  >     n1 = temp;
  >   }
  > ```

  Move the computing of the fibonacci sequence to it's own method.  All you should be passing it is the number of the term you want to compute.

  ```
  unsigned long long int fibonacci(unsigned long long int n)
  {
      if (memoization[n] != -1) return memoization[n];

      return (n < 2)? n : (memoization[n] = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2));
  }
  ```
- You might notice that I have included an array in my previous point named `memoization`.  We want to use this to decrease computation time with the recursion.  Basically, if we have already computed a number, we put it into the array so we don't have to calculate it the next time we want to find a fibonacci number.  If we haven't found the number, we can indicate that in the array by storing a `-1` there instead.

#### Style

- Put all of your variable declarations to separate lines. From *Code Complete, 2nd Edition*, p. 759:

  > With statements on their own lines, the code reads from top to bottom,
  >   instead of top to bottom and left to right. When you’re looking for a
  >   specific line of code, your eye should be able to follow the left
  >   margin of the code. It shouldn’t have to dip into each and every line
  >   just because a single line might contain two statements.
- I can't follow your tabbing scheme.

  > ```
  >         printf("Enter first number > ");
  >   scanf("%d",&n1);
  >         printf("Enter the seconed number > ");
  >   scanf("%d",&n2);
  >         printf("Enter the number of terms > ");
  >   scanf("%d",&limit);
  > ```

  This makes it harder for me to read.  You should align all of the left characters in a block to make them more readable.
- You should declare your parameters as `void` if you don't take in any arguments.

  ```
  int main(void)
  ```

#### Standards

- You should be declaring `i` inside of your `for` loops.<sup>(C99)</sup>

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
  ```

---

## Final code:

- #### Iterative: \$ O(1) \$

  The calculation of the fibonacci sequence here is a bit different than my point I made above.  I didn't mention it, since it was so different than how you were calculating your sequence.  This is one of the most optimal solutions for calculating a fibonacci sequence.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <math.h>

  long long unsigned int fibonacci(long long unsigned int n)
  {
      return round((1/sqrt(5)) * (pow(((1 + sqrt(5)) / 2), n) - pow(((1 - sqrt(5)) / 2), n)));
  }

  int main(void)
  {
      unsigned int num = 0;

      printf("Enter how far to calculate the series: ");
      if (scanf("%i", &num) <= 0)
      {
          puts("Invalid input.");
          return -1;
      }

      for(unsigned int n = 1; n < num + 1; ++n) printf("%llu\n", fibonacci(n));
  }
  ```
- #### Recursion: \$ O(n) \$

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  #define ARRAYLENGTH 100 // keep in mind the result must fit in an llu int (fibonacci values grow rapidly)
                          // you will run into issues after 93, so set the length at 100
  long long int memoization[ARRAYLENGTH];

  long long unsigned int fibonacci(long long unsigned int n)
  {
      if (memoization[n] != -1) return memoization[n];

      return (n < 2)? n : (memoization[n] = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2));
  }

  int main(void)
  {
      unsigned int num = 0;

      for(unsigned int i = 0; i < ARRAYLENGTH; i++) memoization[i] = -1; // preset array

      printf("Enter how far to calculate the series: ");
      if (scanf("%i", &num) <= 0)
      {
          puts("Invalid input.");
          return -1;
      }
      if (num < ARRAYLENGTH)
      {
          for(unsigned int n = 1; n < num + 1; ++n) printf("%llu\n", fibonacci(n));
      }
      else
      {
          puts("Input number is larger than the array length.");
          return -2;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Minor quibble: `signed` to `unsigned` doubles the maximum value, but you specify the same value for both.

Comment: @DavidHarkness Turns out I had the wrong values in there for some reason.  They have been fixed, thanks!

Comment: Iterative is O(1) .... really?

Comment: @rolfl I was more looking inside of the loop, within the function call.

Comment: I would like to point out that the boundaries you gave for different types are true on most modern platforms, but they are not given by any standard. `long` is usually already 64-bits on UNIX systems whereas it's 32-bit on Windows, where you'll need to use `long long`. I strung suggest using `<inttypes.h>`and then using fixed size types such as `uint64_t` where applicable.

Answer (score 5):

Short style comment, you will avoid much future pain by using `fgets()` into a buffer and then `sscanf()` to convert the buffer data to a type rather than using `scanf()` directly.

For more detail, see the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).

Comment: Yes, but the C11 standard `gets_s()` (that replaces `gets()`) would be a better option.

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I get for being an old-timer... hadn't caught up to C11 yet b/c the environment I code in doesn't have compliant compilers on all platforms.

Comment: Your welcome!  I'm still adjusting to the new standards myself.  Hopefully you can stick around and learn them with me!

Comment: @syb0rg  C11dr spec K.3.5.4.1 6 `gets_s()` has the **recommended practice** of "... Consider using `fgets` (...) instead of `gets_s`. ...".  IMO, `gets_s()` is a good replacement for `gets()`, but `fgets()` is better than both of them.  (especially with that pesky `gets_s()` `rsize_t` type.